# Batch process using Google Translation API stops before the end of the file

Tags: php, google-translation-api

I made a daily batch process which insert french (or other languages) data in my database after translating it to English with the Google Translation API. When I use it in a local environment, there is no problem. However, when this process is executing in production, it stops before the end. Do you have an idea about the problem ? Is there a parameter to change in my Google Translation API account?

For example, this morning, process stops at line 54 :

my file :

> 53 Ce code promo vous fait gagner 12% de remise sur les articles de la
>   catégorie sacs multifonctions. C'est pour vous!,12% de réduction
>   Newchic,12% de réduction
>   Newchic,Newchic,newchic,1534118399,code,HOMEBAG12,http://tc.tradetracker.net/?XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
>
> 54 Newchic vous offre avec ce code réduction; 15% de remise sur les
>   articles de la catégorie animal de compagnie. Ne ratez pas cette
>   offre!,15% de réduction Newchic,15% de réduction
>   Newchic,Newchic,newchic,1534291199,code,PETDOG15,http://tc.tradetracker.net/?XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
>
> 55 Découvrez les offres en cours sur le site et gagnez 10% de remise
>   sur les articles de la catégorie vêtements de maternité. Offre valable
>   grâce au code promo. Profitez-en!,10% de réduction Newchic,10% de
>   réduction
>   Newchic,Newchic,newchic,1534636799,code,MOM2018,http://tc.tradetracker.net/?XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=

My program :

```
 $apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

 while($tab=fgetcsv($file,2048,',')){
 .....

       $result=$this->language_curl($apiKey,$text);

       $exclude_list=array("en","und","","erreur");
       if (!in_array($result, $exclude_list)){ 
         $translate_title=$this->translate_curl($apiKey,$title,$result);
         $translate_content=$this->translate_curl($apiKey,$content,$result);

         $content=$translate_content;
         $title=$translate_title;

       }
 ....
 insert database
 ....
 end while
```

...

```
 function language_curl($apiKey,$text){

  $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($text);
  $handle = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($handle);                 
  $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
  $responseCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($handle);
  if($responseCode != 200) {
    $return = "erreur";
  }
  else {
    $return = $responseDecoded['data']['detections'][0][0]['language'];
  }

  return $return;
}

function translate_curl($apiKey,$text,$result){

  $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($text) . '&source=' . $result . '&target=en';
  $handle = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($handle);                 
  $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
  curl_close($handle);
  return $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
}
```

Comment: I would suggest logging all curl responses (before `json_decode`) to a file in your production environment and check for API response errors. You should also check your PHP CLI  logs for `json_decode` errors.

Comment: I used var_dump to see response from curl. I obtain this :
<br>array(1) {
 ["data"]=>
 array(1) {
   ["translations"]=>
   array(1) {
     [0]=>

Comment: @Jamie_D Today, at the last line, I have <br>array(1) {
 ["data"]=>
 array(1) {
   ["translations"]=>
   array(1) {
     [0]=>
     array(1) {
       ["